# Is it possible to edit the data returned by docker inspect?

Tags: docker

`docker inspect` returns all sorts of interesting information about a docker image or container (or another object).

Where is this information stored? Is it possible to edit it?

Comment: Depending on what you're trying to achieve, you may be best off setting a label.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it's not possible to edit the 'built in' configuration and state information returned by `docker inspect`. However if you want to *add* information to `docker inspect` then you can look into adding labels to your images / containers and then introspecting that (as label information is returned by `docker inspect`).

Official docs on Labelling (various different objects) can be found [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/labels-custom-metadata/).

Answer (score 8):

### Manual modification

as `johnharris85` says.
Until now (17.12) docker no API to edit container's most options.

The only thing we can do is edit config files on disk:

---

Generally, the config was in folder `/var/lib/docker/containers/<containerID>*/`

- config.v2.json
- hostconfig.json

edit them, restart docker service **immediately**, new config will load.

// tested in docker 17.12

see also:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/49371983/4896468

// find out the dir (of config.v2.json)

```bash
dirname `docker inspect $container_name | jq '.[].HostnamePath' -r`
```

### about `Synology NAS` docker

Recently I realized the docker cmd in `Synology NAS DSM system`
has ability to edit container setttings via cmdline or webgui (without re-create it, or fully restart docker service)

#### the cmdline

here is the `docker update` diff:

- docker 20.10.3 from DSM 6.2
- docker 19.03.6 from ubuntu 18.04

```
$ docker update --help
 
 Usage:  docker update [OPTIONS] CONTAINER [CONTAINER...]
 
 Update configuration of one or more containers
 
 Options:
       --blkio-weight uint16        Block IO (relative weight), between 10 and 1000, or 0 to disable (default 0)
+      --cap-add list               Add Linux capabilities
+      --cap-drop list              Drop Linux capabilities
       --cpu-period int             Limit CPU CFS (Completely Fair Scheduler) period
       --cpu-quota int              Limit CPU CFS (Completely Fair Scheduler) quota
       --cpu-rt-period int          Limit the CPU real-time period in microseconds
       --cpu-rt-runtime int         Limit the CPU real-time runtime in microseconds
   -c, --cpu-shares int             CPU shares (relative weight)
       --cpus decimal               Number of CPUs
       --cpuset-cpus string         CPUs in which to allow execution (0-3, 0,1)
       --cpuset-mems string         MEMs in which to allow execution (0-3, 0,1)
+  -e, --env list                   Set environment variables
+      --env-file list              Read in a file of environment variables
       --kernel-memory bytes        Kernel memory limit
+      --link list                  Add link to another container
   -m, --memory bytes               Memory limit
       --memory-reservation bytes   Memory soft limit
       --memory-swap bytes          Swap limit equal to memory plus swap: '-1' to enable unlimited swap
       --pids-limit int             Tune container pids limit (set -1 for unlimited)
+      --privileged                 Give extended privileges to this container
+  -p, --publish list               Publish a container's port(s) to the host
       --restart string             Restart policy to apply when a container exits
+  -v, --volume list                Bind mount a volume
```

#### the WebGUI

[image: DSM_docker_edit.png]

--

I'm not sure where to get this enhanced version docker.
wish someday this can be implemented in offical version.

BTW: DSM webui is the most powerfull docker webui I have ever use.
you can see it not only UI, also custmized the docker service.
//maybe someday, implement a similar docker ui like that.

### about `live-restore`

nowadays docker daemon have a `live-restore` option,
which can restart daemon without stop other container.

It makes life easier.

```json
/etc/docker/daemon.json
{
  "live-restore": true
}
```

https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/live-restore/

Comment: It's very important to restart docker service `sudo systemctl restart docker` immediately after editing `config.v2.json`. Otherwise, docker commands will overwrite your changes to `config.v2.json`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, 
@johnharris points out there is no direct editing api

@yurenchen is correct that editing `/var/lib/docker/containers/<containerID>/hostconfig.json` then restarting the docker daemon will update the output of `docker inpect <containerID>`

During a docker update, the default runtime changed from `oci` to `runc` and I was unable to restart a stack of containers.
Output from `sudo cat /var/lib/docker/<containerID>/hostconfig.json | jq .Runtime` was `"oci"` but needed to be `"runc"` after update.

Manually started `sudo docker start <short_containerID>`